# opencart sql error editing products

Tags: sql, opencart, editing, product

I use opencart 1.5.5.1 When editing a product I get this error below and I can not edit product

```
"Warning: mysql_query(): Unable to save result set in /home/tabpcmar/domains/tabpcmarket.ir/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 22Notice: Error: Subquery returns more than 1 row
Error No: 1242
SELECT DISTINCT *, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cd1.name ORDER BY level SEPARATOR ' > ') 
FROM oc_category_path cp LEFT JOIN oc_category_description cd1 ON (cp.path_id =  
cd1.category_id AND cp.category_id != cp.path_id) WHERE cp.category_id = c.category_id  
AND cd1.language_id = '2' GROUP BY cp.category_id) AS path, (SELECT keyword FROM  
oc_url_alias WHERE query = 'category_id=63') AS keyword FROM oc_category c LEFT JOIN  
oc_category_description cd2 ON (c.category_id = cd2.category_id) WHERE c.category_id  
= '63' AND cd2.language_id = '2' in  
/home/tabpcmar/domains/tabpcmarket.ir/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 50 "
```

Comment: Have you checked your database, it is possible you have two rows with the same id, or something like that, does this happen for all products or only one?

Comment: The error says the sub query returns more than one row. Check the result of your inner query

Comment: this happen for all products and I dont edit any products.

Comment: How do I solve the problem?